# jQuery UI slider handle jumps

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I'm using the jQuery UI slider. If I change the height of the handle to more than the standard (20px), and click on the slider handle and move it in any direction - the handle of the slider jumps a few pixels.

I would like it not to bounce.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UltraFreizer/dB3bH/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle{
        height: 30px;   
    } 
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $(".slider-vertical").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider-vertical"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to change the bottom margin of the `.ui-slider-handle` like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dB3bH/3/)**

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle{
    height: 30px;   
    margin-bottom:-15px;
}
```

The handle's position is related to its height. The handle by default has a height of 1.2em and to center the handle over its position it is given a negative bottom margin of 1/2 that, or -0.6em, so if you need to re-size the handle you have to adjust the bottom margin as well.

Basically margin-bottom = 0 - height / 2

Comment: Great, great, thanks a lot!!!
I was looking for a solution to this problem for about 20 hours, and the solution turned out to be so simple. :)))

Comment: The answer is found. Topic is closed.

Comment: Excellent answer. My specific problem was rotated 90 degrees, so sliding the slider right-left. Same answer tho. margin-left = 0 - width /2